# In nodejs, request custom header not received from nginx if NOT hardcoded

Tags: node.js, nginx

Node receives a hard coded custom header value from nginx proxy. However when i pass the value for the custom header, then it seems to be ignored and the custom header is not even received on the node server side.

Following works:

```
location / {
...
proxy_set_header mycustomheader "hard coded value";
...
}
```

In above case, in NodeJs side, i could receive it and mycustomheader is present in the req.headers.

...
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));   # prints mycustomheader and value
...

However the following doesnt work:

```
    location / { 
 proxy_set_header mycustomheader $http_mycustomvalue;    #mycustomvalue passed in req header  
}
```

> ...
> console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));   # No mycustomheader present
> ...

Note that mycustomvalue is sent in request header from a nodejs program. I could confirm receipt of it by passing it to another nodejs server.

Why NodeJs could receive value of  mycustomheader when i hardcode it and Why there is no trace of mycustomheader in req.headers when i pass a value? Are there any configuration or setting on NodeJS side that blocks or fetching the custom header in request when the value is passed thru nginx?

Comment: It should work exactly as you expected. Moreover, every request header should be passed to the backend as-is (except of `Host` and `Connection` headers which are redefined by default). Check the actual request header value adding `$http_mycustomvalue` variable to nginx access log defining a temporary custom access log format.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Figured out that the value was not set in subsequent requests and that caused the issue.